# How do I make this if then else script

Tags: macos, bash, if-statement

I've been trying to make this **if then else script** but its wrong every time.

I am brand new at this, maybe I have taken more than I can chew but I am trying to make a script that runs at launch that does this

If file exists /Users/Bob/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist

then do nothing

if file does not exist ( i assume this is "else") then move file from /Library/Application\ Support/Bookmarks.plist to /Users/Bob/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist

Any feedback is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the script? It looks like you forgot to include it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described could be written like that in pseudo code:

```
if file_exists("/Users/Bob/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist")
   exit

if not file_exists("/Users/Bob/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist")
   move("/Library/Application\ Support/Bookmarks.plist", "/Users/Bob/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist")
```

As you can see, the first "branch" is not really used, as you anyway plan to ignore this case.

But if we assume, that in the first case, you actually want to do something, like print a nice message, you could write it like that:

```
if file_exists("/Users/Bob/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist")
    print("Nothing to do!")
else
   move("/Library/Application\ Support/Bookmarks.plist", "/Users/Bob/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist")
```

As you can see, in the this example, the "else" part is equivalent to saying "if not file_exists(...)". You could also reverse the order by using "not":

```
if not file_exists("/Users/Bob/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist")
    move("/Library/Application\ Support/Bookmarks.plist", "/Users/Bob/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist")
else
   print("Nothing to do!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DST="/Users/Bob/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist"
SRC="/Library/Application\ Support/Bookmarks.plist"
if [ ! -f "$DST" ]; then
  mv "$SRC" "$DST"
fi
```

This will see if the destination exists. If not, it will move the file. Realistically there should be additional error checking, and I'm not certain a move is the best approach, since there would no longer be an "original" file.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly as well, thank you. +1